# Fabric JS: Why are my shapes are being replaced with images on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, caching, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to create a drawing app for a school project with fabric js and want to allow a user to save their drawing to my database and reopen for editing etc. I know some of this is redundant but I have been trying various ways to clear the canvas to make way for the selected one to be opened.

My chrome cache is disabled and I have also used this line of code:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;
```

I am opening the json to my canvas from my database everytime I upload. If I open a file from the database which contains 5 images (png or svg) and open it to my canvas then decide to open a different drawing which only 10 shapes (rectangles, circles etc) the canvas will open with those 5 images that were previously on the canvas having replaced 5 of the shapes and then the other 5 shapes will be there too...?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "canvasLoadByName.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {canvas_name: canvas_name},
        success: function (result){

                //alert(canvas_name + " has been selected!"),

                $("#Open").click(function() {
                    //canvas.getActiveGroup().forEachObject(function(o){ canvas.remove(o) }); canvas.discardActiveGroup().renderAll();
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    canvas.clear();
                    canvas.loadFromJSON();
                    canvas.renderAll();
                    canvas.loadFromJSON(result, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
                    fabric.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it was this button:

```
$("Open").click(function(){}
```

which was causing the problems. I wanted it so it didn't open upon immediate selection of the dropdown list but rather they would choose 'ok' when they pick the file they wanted. Without having to click open it works fine... :s